# zmq swap and HWM

Tags: zeromq

From DOC

> ØMQ provides something called a "swap", which is a disk file that
>   holds messages we can't store to the queue

Will the messages overflown to the swap incase of HWM reached be sent to the receiver once it comes back [with the identity] or starts performing well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DOC](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt)

The ZMQ_SWAP option shall set the disk offload (swap) size for the specified socket. A socket which has ZMQ_SWAP set to a non-zero value may exceed its high water mark; in this case outstanding messages shall be offloaded to storage on disk rather than held in memory

So, the messages will be sent to the receiver. I tested it with

**PUSH Socket**

```
$sender = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$sender->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_HWM, 1);
$sender->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SWAP, 1000);
$sender->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9090");

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
     $sender->send($i);
    echo "message sent";
    usleep(100);
}
```

and

**PULL Socket**

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();

$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_HWM, 25000);
$receiver->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SWAP, 25000);
$receiver->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9090");
$i = 0;
while (1) {
     $msg = $receiver->recv();
     echo "$i $msg \n";
     $i++;
}
```

By Starting PUSH socket first with no PULLer

Comment: From the docs:

**ZMQ_SWAP option has been removed. Symptom: compile failures on ZMQ_SWAP. Solution: redesign any code that uses this functionality.**