# how to specify zmq swap file path

Tags: zeromq

I am using the ZeroMQ C++ libary. The `ZMQ_SWAP` option puts outstanding messages to storage on disk. How can I specify a swap file? The `zmq_setsokopt` function only sets swap size like this:

```
uint64_t swap = 25000000;
zmq_setsockopt (publisher, ZMQ_SWAP, &swap, sizeof (swap));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZMQ_SWAP` has been removed in v3.x of 0MQ, due to problems implementing it.
As far as I can tell, the option to specify the path was never implemented.

If you're using this option in v2.1.x, you'll need to redesign in any case in order to upgrade to a more recent version of 0MQ.

See [here](https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564942/zmq-swap-and-hwm) for more details.